# Make UItableview cell height equal to it's child UItableview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3

I have a UItableview cell that is contain a UItableview, I need to make height of that cell equal to height of it's child UItableview.
Image below explain what I need to do.

[image: here]

Comment: @Larme I not need to scroll nside the subtableView.
What you suggest to achieve what I need?

Comment: Seems to me you shouldn't need to nest a tableview within a tableview at all. I would Implement 'Main Cellx' as a header and 'Sub Cellx' as a cell.

Comment: @FryAnEgg I'm beginner, can you told me how to do that, can you provide me an example.

Comment: Yeah, I can help you out. It might take me a few hours to get back to my sample code. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First see my ViewController,which has one tableview(tblview) and UITableViewCell(CustomTableViewCell) ,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tblview:UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tblview.delegate = self
        self.tblview.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomTableViewCell.identifier) as! CustomTableViewCell
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

Then see my CustomTableViewCell which has one table view and one label in a cell.See,

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let identifier = "CustomTableViewCell"

    @IBOutlet var tblviewCell:UITableView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        self.tblviewCell.delegate = self
        self.tblviewCell.dataSource = self
        tblviewCell.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {

        let heighToReturn = self.tblviewCell.contentSize.height + 20 // upper and down space
        return CGSize(width: self.tblviewCell.contentSize.width, height: heighToReturn)
    }

}

extension CustomTableViewCell:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: customCell.identifier) as! customCell
        cell.lblname?.text = "Vikas"
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }

}

class customCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let identifier = "customCell"

    @IBOutlet weak var lblname :UILabel?

}
```

So, if you give tableview content size height in **systemLayoutSizeFitting** method then problem will be solve.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do table header cells. The cell needs to be prototyped in the storyboard and subclassed (if needs to be configured). Then override the following funcs in the table view delegate. Alternatively, you can generate a view on the fly and return that from viewForHeaderInSection.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 150
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ConferenceHeaderCell") as! ConferenceDetailHeaderCell
        // configure cell 
        return headerCell
    }
```

For the cells themselves, it's very similar:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ConferenceUserCell", for: indexPath) as! ConferenceDetail_TVCell

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
```

and depending, you may to implement 'heightForRowAtIndexPath'